# Auto Layout ignores changes to layout margins

Tags: ios, xamarin, layout, autolayout

I have a custom `ParentView` with one child view `ChildView`.

The `ChildView` is pinned to `ParentView`'s layout margins.

Then, at runtime, when I change the `LayoutMargins` property of the `ParentView`, it seems to be ignored altogether.

I do either `parentView.LayoutMargins = new UIEdgeInsets(12, 12, 12, 12)` or `UIEdgeInsets.Zero` in the MVVM binding implementation (double-checked that binding really happens and the method is invoked).

However, on the UI, the insets remain at the default level of 8 from every side.

Silly as it seems, I tried calling `SetNeedsLayout()`, `SetNeedsDisplay()`, `SetNeedsUpdateConstraints()` alongside the above assignment, but nothing seems to help.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you calling `setNeedsLayout()` on the parent view ?

Comment: Yes, on the `ParentView` (but not its parent view)

Comment: Is your `ParentView` a root view of a `UIViewController`?

Comment: No, it's not. It is deep within the controller's view hierarchy.